# calling a constructor/prototype method javascript method in html

Tags: javascript

I am totally new to JS (as such I use C and python) and I have been given a JS file for which I would like to create an onclick event for.

So, I took this on as a learning exercise, and I was confronted with something like this:

```
new ModeDetect,
QuasiNewton.prototype = {
    width: 1024,
    height: 768,
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    showQuasiNewton: function(a) {
//more stuff here..
    },
```

The aim is to use something like this in html, to call `showQuasiNewton`:

```
<a href="#" onclick="showQuasiNewton()">Display simulation results</a>
```

The above obviously does not work - since the JS seems to have a constructor and a `prototype` and I was wondering how I could call the function `showQuasiNewton`

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I have no clue on JS.. :(

Comment: create an object of QuasiNewton() and add an on click event listener to the anchor tag.

Comment: can you post your js file code here? very difficult to tell from the few lines given

Comment: hope [how does javascript prototype work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work?rq=1) and [javascript prototype dynamically add div onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22034243/using-javascript-prototype-need-to-dynamically-add-div-onclick) help